# Creating a completely offline installer using simple-cdd

Tags: debian, install

I'm trying to create a custom CD using my own minimal debian installed setup.

I just simply typed `build-simple-cdd`. The process was successful, but when I tested it on my virtualbox and disabling the network, it looks for the kernel.

Did I miss anything on my setup?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have text left behind? "it looks for" what?

Comment: Hehe. . . one of the reason why I hate copy and paste. Edited.

Comment: How do you know that “it” (what?) looks for the kernel? Presumably from an error message, so reproduce it here. As you probably can't copy-paste, transcribe the messages (as search engine fodder) and post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your image doesn't support the architecture of your vm (e.g., 64-bit iso but your vm is specified as 32-bit).

Mount the CD and check the contents manually to make sure that what you expect to be there is actually there.